# What is the difference between "light" and "slight"?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

What is the difference between "light" and "slight"? 
How to use these words correctly in different cases?

Comment: I thought this was a decent question. Yes the words can be looked up in a dictionary, but they both have multiple meanings which are very different. The OP would need to know firstly which meanings are comparable, and even if they did work that out from the context, there is also a degree of understanding the difference between *weight* and *mass*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both words have multiple meanings, but the meanings which are synonymous would be:

**light**: weighing very little, or less than average.

**slight**: small in degree; inconsiderable.

*Light* is therefore a reference to *weight*, whereas *slight* refers to *size*, or *mass*. Obviously, an object's mass and weight are very [different things](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-heavier-a-ton-of-bricks-or-a-ton-of-feathers).

When said about a *person*, "slight" suggests that they are thin, not very tall, or do not look very strong. We don't usually describe an *object* as being "slight", but we might say "a slight *amount*" of something, meaning little of it.

Either an object or a person could be described as "light" if it is light in weight.